# Using array.prototype.filter() method to filter based on arguments from another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have an array of objects which I want to filter based on values from an array of rendered checkboxes. (ie: so if 2 of 5 checkboxes are checked I want to filter the data by parameters specified by those checkboxes.

I have been able to do a quick and dirty version of the solution where I hardcode all expected values of the checkbox array but it is really unnecessary I think

```
// Filter variable (array of objects)

const filterValues = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "min": 0,
        "max": 5,
        "checked": true
    }..... ,
 ]
```

```
// Filter function taking in:
// dataList (an array of objects where each one has a [length]  )
// filterValues (an array of objects as defined above)

    const filterData = (dataList, filterValues) => {
        return dataList.filter(item =>
            (filterValues[0].checked && 
            (filterValues[0].max >= item.length) && 
            (item.length > filterValues[0].min))
            || (filterValues[1].checked && .... (....)
    )
```

I am trying to use some combination of higher order functions within filterData to map out a list of parameters which the .filter() can then use to properly filter the data.

Thank you very much for your help

Comment: this will help `https://codepen.io/piotrek/pen/mXpRmQ?editors=1010`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [**`some`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) inside `filter` like this:

```
const filterData = (dataList, filterValues) =>
   dataList.filter(item =>
      filterValues.some(f => f.checked &&
         (f.max >= item.length) &&
         (item.length > f.min)
      )
   )
```